# why is not grid layout enabled by default in google chrome?

Tags: layout, grid

Grid layout is supported by default in Internet Explorer 10 and we are already at 11, but in Google Chrome, which is the most popular browser, it is still an experimental feature.

Since grid layout is a great time-saver for HTML developers and avoids many problems and shortcomings of other well-supported page layout tools, I am asking why we can't use it right now.

I understand the W3C grid-layout spec is still a WIP, but I expected some stable, basic things to be implemented by browsers before the standard is completed by default, else what kind of browser war is this? I hope someone from Chrome dev-team can answer me here.

Comment: I apologize if I go out of topic here, but why don't we start a petition for google to implement basic grid layout features properly right away?

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about **web development** which is off-topic at Pro Webmasters. Web development questions may be asked at [so] but be sure to read their [FAQ](http://stackoverflow.com/help) before posting to ensure your question meets their guidelines.

Answer (score 1):

It's not just Chrome.   Grid layout isn't supported by the majority of browsers.

From: http://caniuse.com/#feat=css-grid

[image]

You won't be able to use this feature until it is enabled at least in Firefox, Chrome, and Safari.   If you care about mobile, then Android browser as well.

Most web developers wait until a feature is supported by 80% or more of their visitors' browsers before using it.   In general, that can take *years*.    I would have liked to start using transparent PNG alpha layers and min-width CSS years before I was actually able to do so because IE was the lone browser that didn't support them.   Even once IE did support them, Microsoft doesn't push users to upgrade their browsers and it takes years for usage of old versions of the browser to dwindle.      At least with Chrome, Google pushes updates out and most users upgrade frequently.   Once the feature is enabled, it should be available to use quickly.

Comment: Until all browsers will support grid layout, I am going to use hidden tables for layout as an act of protest, but also because there is no better alternative.